# Inequality Proof: $(x-y)^n\leq x^n-y^n$

Tags: inequality

$\forall x\geq y\geq 0,n\geq 1$ show that :

$$(x-y)^n\leq x^n-y^n$$

If I have tried something, it would appear here after I have changed this placeholder text.

Comment: What attempts have you made?

Comment: Use induction hypothesis

Answer (score 6):

By the change of variables $a=x-y$ and $b=y$, it is equivalent to proving
$$
a^n+b^n\leq (a+b)^n
$$
for all $a,b\geq 0$. This follows from the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:
Perform induction on $n$. For $n = 1$, this is trivial. Assume the inductive hypothesis $(x-y)^{k} \leq x^{k}-y^{k}$. Now $$(x-y)^{k+1} \leq (x^{k}-y^{k})(x-y)  = x^{k+1}-x^{k}y-y^{k}x - y^{k+1}\text{.}$$
Since $y, x \geq 0$, what can you do to finish this off?